# Type Int32Array highest and lowest interger?

Tags: javascript, buffer, 32-bit

I've done an experiment for lowest and highest integer value and if I go higher it traverses to negative or positive respectively.

```
var x = new Int32Array(3);
    x[0] = 2147483647;
    x[1] = -2147483648;
    console.log(x[0]);
    console.log(x[1]);
    console.log(x.length);
    //Results:
    //2147483647 cannot go above unless -2147483648*
    //-2147483648 cannot go above unless 2147483647*
    //2
```

Could someone explain why this happens in JavaScript? Why those values? In other browsers, mobile devices and operating systems, would it be the same affect?

Comment: Here is an explanation for the highest/lowest integers; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin/307200#307200

Comment: @D.Soderberg: That's for the number type, not `Int32Array`'s values.

Comment: Oh sorry, I messed up :/

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone explain why this happens in JavaScript?

It's not just JavaScript, virtually all programming languages use the same underlying mechanism ("Two's Complement") for their integer types. This is a feature of Two's Complement integers: When you go out of range, you wrap around. `Int32Array` is an array of 32-bit two's complement integers. (Whereas JavaScript's normal number type isn't; it's an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point number.)

Let's look at the bits of 2147483647:

```
01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

when you add 1 to that, you get

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

...which is -2147483648. And of course, if you take 1 away from it again, you get the original (2147483647) back.

More about two's complement on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

> Why those values?

Because with signed 32-bit ints, that's the available range. -2<sup>32</sup> through 2<sup>32</sup>-1, inclusive. If you were using an `Int8Array`, the range would be -128 (-2<sup>8</sup>) through 127 (2<sup>8</sup>-1).

> In other browsers, mobile devices and operating systems, would it be the same affect?

Yes. If they didn't, they wouldn't be implementing `Int32Array` correctly.